# Are 95% of engineers in India unfit for software development jobs?

Tags: technology

[This article](http://www.gadgetsnow.com/jobs/95-engineers-in-india-unfit-for-software-development-jobs-claims-report/articleshow/58278224.cms) has been circulating on a few sites recently, which has as its headline:

> 95% engineers in India unfit for software development jobs, claims report

With the claim:

> According to a study by employability assessment company Aspiring Minds, only 4.77% candidates can write the correct logic for a programme -- a minimum requirement for any programming job.

and:

> "Sixty nine per cent of candidates from top 100 colleges are able to write a compilable code versus rest of the colleges where only 31% are able to write a compilable code," the report said.

It seems provocative but it is getting a fair number of reposts around the Internet.

Is that claim true? Or is there any corroborating evidence somewhere? Or have they misrepresented information in such a way to drive this claim?

Comment: From my experience? 95% of engineers from _everywhere_ are unfit for software development jobs - be it India, USA, Brazil, whatever. Most of the people that manage to get a engineer diploma can't program at all. Having good developers is somewhat of a privilege...

Comment: Looks like they do this yearly for some clicks! http://www.aspiringminds.com/news/aspiring-minds-releases-5th-national-employability-report-engineers also when was every engineer into software development, when was every job world wide available to a citizen from any other country?

Comment: The study was done on, "36,000 engineering students form [sic] IT related branches." These are not engineers, and aren't necessarily coders. You need to correctly restate their claims in your question.

Comment: @BobTheAverage  If the article misstates the results of the study, you should explain that in an answer (with citations), not in a comment.

Comment: To add to what @TSar wrote, [Why Can't Programmers.. Program?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)

Comment: There's a big difference between correct logic and correct syntax (the latter being "compilable code" in more technical terms)

Comment: With all the garbage being posted these days, someone should call the sanitation engineers to haul it away.

Comment: That article is so full of BS that I don't even know where to begin. "over 2/3 could not even write code that compiles" Yeah, right, that is a *fantastic* criteria to judge if a person is suitable for a software development job. I have about 10 years of experience, and still cannot guarantee that my code will compile in the 1st attempt, but hey, that is not exactly my priority when I write code. I focus more on the important things like getting the design right, because compilation is ... uhm, you know ... what compiler does, and I know how to fix compilation errors.

Comment: I also love how the article takes "ability to write compilable code" as a criterion for "doing a software development *job*". The author clearly has no idea what he is talking about if he doesn't know the difference between developing software and doing a software development *job* (even if I accept that "writing compilable code" is a valid criterion for judging "develop software" ability).

Comment: Lots of comments about this, not very many answers... ;-)

Comment: A friend told me that his company hired an expert contractor to fix uncompilable c++ code.  After 3 months he finished the task and left. When the compiled code was run, it didn't work as expected.  It turned out, he commented out the code that causing compile error.